# Ruby keyword arguments best practice

Tags: ruby, styles, keyword-argument

Ruby keyword (named) arguments have been around for some time now. I was wondering if there have emerged any guidlines for best practices, or what your opinions are on how to best use them.

For instance, is it OK to mix named keywords with unnamed arguments, e.g. if one argument is required and the rest are optional, or is it generally recommended to stick to either style for one and the same method? Consider the following method:

```
def parse_file(path, optional_option1: true, optional_option2: false, optional_option3: 42)
```

What's the lowest number of arguments you think are appropriate to use named keywords for. Is it redundant for just 2 or 3, or does it make the code easier to read even when there are very few arguments?

In most examples I've seen keyword arguments are used for optional arguments and they sure make code easier to read than having to specify the default values of several parameters in a method call, just to be able specify the last parameter, but how useful are they for required arguments?

I know this is rather subjective but I'm curious to see how others use this feature.

Answer (score 2):

I usually prefer to keep it as simple and flexible as possible. In your case it would be something like:

```
def parse_file(path, options={})
  # You can keep this hash outside this function
  defaults = {
    optional_option1: true,
    optional_option2: false, 
    optional_option3: 42
  }
  settings = defaults.merge(options)
  # ...
```

You can perform some validation:

```
def parse_file(path, options={})
  raise ArgumentError.new('Missing required argument: optional_option1:') unless options[:optional_option1]
```

And so on. This would be my advice and how I use to work with my company